# Factors that exist in the testing set but not the training set in R

Tags: r

So I split my dataset into 80% training and 20% testing data. Then I build 3 models (KNN, rndom forest, and SVM) with the training dataset and predict the testing data with each model. Finally, I ensemble the models (make prediction with the maximum vote, say if 2 of the 3 models say "Yes", then the prediction will be a "Yes".)

However, i got the following warning (in the confusion Matrix):

```
Warning messages:
1: In levels(reference) != levels(data) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In confusionMatrix.default(as.factor(predict_df$number), test_data[,  :
  Levels are not in the same order for reference and data. Refactoring data to match.
```

For warning 1, I check the `levels()` of the training and testing set, they are NOT the same in which the testing set has two extra factor variables (that don't exist in the training set). What can I do to fix this? This does NOT happen with indivudal (not the ensemble) model and prediction.

For warning 2, I guess fixing the first warning will help solving the second warning.

My code for the confusionMatrix if needed:

```
confusionM = confusionMatrix(as.factor(predict_df$number), test_data[,122])
```

where `predict_df` is a data frame with the data + a column `number` that consists predictions with maximum vote from 3 models (KNN, random forest, and SVM)

I looked into this [Handling different Factor Levels in Train and Test data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40536257/handling-different-factor-levels-in-train-and-test-data) , but it doesn't solved my problem.

Edited for comment:

```
# split data
size = floor(0.8 * nrow(df))
t_row = sample(seq_len(nrow(df)), size = size)
train_data = df[t_row,]
test_data = df[-t_row,]
```

Comment: How did you split the data? Can you post the code you have used? Generally speaking, when you sample from a factor, if the subset does not contain all levels, the levels are the same, you will have to call `droplevels` to get rid of unused factor levels.

Comment: edited. I would say i didn't sample from a factor but rather sample the whole dataset that includes a factor column.

Comment: That code should give factor columns in train and test with the same factor levels, though some of those levels might be present in one of the data sets but not in the other. What do `str(train_data)` and `str(test_data)` show?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, my colleague was sick and had been super busy. for both `str(train_data)` and `str(test_data)`, I got class numeric. But I did use `as.factor()` when dealing with the confusionMatrix

Comment: Try something like `levs <- union(predict_df$number, test[,122])` to get all numbers and `factor(predict_df$number, levels = levs)` in `confusionMatrix `.

Comment: like `confusionMatrix(as.factor(predict_df$number), test[,122], levels = levs)` ?

Comment: No, I mean something like `pred_num <- factor(predict$number, levels = levs); test_num <- factor(test[,122], levels = levs)` and then `confusionMatrix(pred_num, test_num)`.

Comment: great! I got no warnings! But i got the same accuracy value as the ones with warnings. So... i can in fact ignore the warning?

Comment: Yes, you can. See how the second warning message ends, it says it will solve the problem on its own.  And the first one is about the levels' lengths, so there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thank you!